# How to send a Asp label value( from server side) from popup window to parent window dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

Trying to send label value from popupwindow to parent window drop down list

Comment: I weould try some javascript

Comment: Do you open the popup through client-side javascript, like using jquery ui dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it by using, (Changed to client side)
popup window code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
             function updateParent(test) {                
            var oVal = test;
            window.opener.updateParent(oVal);
            window.top.close();
        }
    </script>
```

Parent window code:

```
function updateParent(oVal) {
            var region = oVal;
            $('#ddlreg option:contains(' + region + ')').each(function () {
                if ($(this).text() == region) {
                    $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a global variable that you pass this value in it

Create **Global.asax file,**  In it create `public static string X;`

Go to your page access the dropdown value save it in this X by calling Global File

Then Restore in in your Main Page